# 'make' command error when building cpp program [Oracle- undefined reference to `LdiDateCheck']

Tags: c++, linux, oracle, redhat

I tried to build my c++ program using make command in redhat 5.4 (Tikanga) and then I got following errors

> /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `LdiDateCheck'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to`OraMemInit'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `lxkRegexpCountLob'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to`lxmdigx'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `ztchi'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to`sltsmxi'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `ons_shutdown_wtimeout_ctx'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to`lxhebc'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `LhtStrSearch'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libocci.so: undefined reference to`LdiInterToString'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libocci.so: undefined reference to `lnxdec'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to`ssOswPthread_mutex_lock'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `lxscat'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to`lnxnucopt'
>   /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `lfpcd2cf'

........and more.. (ask me if you want to see the full log)

Can you suggest me a way to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're either not linking a library or you're linking the wrong version.

Comment: Thanks vincent, as you said I was linking the wrong version and now problem solved